# Meaning of icons next to object type name in snapshot

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-leaks, heap-memory, snapshot

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional.

What are the meaning of the flame icons next to Object Type name in the Snapshot pane?

The icons are displayed, when in the lower part of the Snapshot pane, I select Referenced Types.

[image: flame icons in Snapshot pane]

I tried hovering the mouse pointer over the icon, no tool tip was displayed.

Comment: Likely representing something "Hot", might be due to large number of allocations, i.e. a performance concern, or possibly because some type of suspected memory leak. In either case it is likely something of interest.

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is to highlight execution hot paths in the profiler call tree, named Expand hot path. Click on it and it will automatically expand the complete call path (hot path).

The hot path is the most expensive call path based on sample count (sampling analysis) or execution time (instrumentation analysis). The hot path shows the branch of the application call tree that has the highest inclusion sample or inclusion time.

For details, please refer to: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improving-visual-studio-performance-with-the-new-instrumentation-tool/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The link refers to Visual Studio 2022. In that post, the icons are next to function names. In Visual Studio 2019 the icons are next to data type names. When the icons are next to data type, is the meaning the same "the most expensive call path based on sample count (sampling analysis) or execution time (instrumentation analysis). The hot path shows the branch of the application call tree that has the highest inclusion sample or inclusion time." ?

Comment: @AnthonyAntans If you click on those data types, will you be shown data related to time consumption and usage?